# Angular view not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am quite new to Angular.js and think I am missing something small but important here.

To learn angular I am building this little panel to route video sources to destinations.

I have a list of sources and a list of destinations (each destination with 2 slots).
These will later be loaded from an API, but for now are defined in the js.

When I select one of the sources, the "selectedSource" var gets set with the clicked source. 
When I than click a destination-slot is sets that slot's content with the "selectedSource" object.

The console log tells me that the thumb url of the slot has updated, but my html does not show the updated image. I've already messed around with "apply" altough I don't beleieve that is the way to go.

See my simplified code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/f4Tgf/

```
function app($scope, $filter) {
$scope.selectedSource = null;

$scope.sources =  {
    source1 : {id:'source1', thumbUrl:'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/1/'},
    source2 : {id:'source2', thumbUrl:'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/2/'},
    source3 : {id:'source3', thumbUrl:'http://lorempixel.com/100/100/sports/3/'}
}

$scope.destinations = {
    dest1 : {id:'dest1', slots: {slot1 : $scope.sources.source2,slot2 : $scope.sources.source3} }
}

$scope.selectSource = function(source){
    if($scope.selectedSource == source){
        // toggle the selected source off if it is already selected
        $scope.selectedSource = null;
    }else{
        $scope.selectedSource = source;  
    }
}

$scope.selectSlot = function(slot){
    slot = $scope.selectedSource;
    console.log(slot.thumbUrl);

    //reset selected source
    $scope.selectedSource = null;
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<body >
<div ng-app ng-controller="app" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">





        <!-- SOURCES -->
        <div id="source-container" class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                     <h3 class="panel-title">Sources</h3>

                </div>
                <div class="panel-body row">
                    <!-- Show all sources -->
                    <div ng-repeat="source in sources" ng-class="{selected: source==selectedSource}" ng-click="selectSource(source)" class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{source.thumbUrl}}" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- SOURCES -->


        <!-- DESTINATIONS -->
        <div id="sink-container" class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                     <h3 class="panel-title">Destination</h3>

                </div>
                <div class="panel-body row">
                    <!-- Show all destinations -->
                    <div ng-repeat="destination in destinations" ng-class="{available: selectedSource!=null}">
                        <div class="thumbnail">
                            <div ng-repeat="slot in destination.slots" ng-click="selectSlot(slot)">
                                <img class="img-responsive" src="{{slot.thumbUrl}}" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END DESTINATIONS -->


    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

(before you tell me to use services and so, please remember: this is a first try-learning project)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dJLrM/ similar to the answer provided...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to change the value parameter, `slot`, of the `selectSlot()` function instead of the destination's array of slots itself. Since you can have one ore more destinations slots from a list of destinations then the most probable solution would be to change `selectSlot()` to accept the current destinations array of slots and the key of the slot that you want to change.

Simply change this **HTML** code from

```
<div ng-repeat="slot in destination.slots" ng-click="selectSlot(slot)">
```

to

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, slot) in destination.slots" ng-click="selectSlot(destination.slots, key)">
```

and in your **JAVASCRIPT** `selectSlot()` definition should be

```
$scope.selectSlot = function(slots, key){
    slots[key] = $scope.selectedSource;

    //reset selected source
    $scope.selectedSource = null;
}
```

See this [UPDATE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ryeballar/f4Tgf/5/) to view it in action.

Note: you can refer to [AngularJS' documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) regarding ng-repeat's (key, value) synatx.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is a pure JavaScript problem.

In you `selectSlot()`:

```
slot = $scope.selectedSource;
```

this operation does not actually assign `$scope.selectedSource` to one of `$scope.destinations.dest1.slots` as you expected.

You may want to do it this way:

```
    slot.id = $scope.selectedSource.id;
    slot.thumbUrl = $scope.selectedSource.thumbUrl;
```

That will work.

But please also note that in your case, you initialize `$scope.destinations.dest1.slots` as tow objects of `$scope.sources`, that means change the slot in `$scope.destinations.dest1.slots` also results in changing the corresponding one in `$scope.sources`.  It will work fine if as you said, the destinations "will later be loaded from an API".